# Testing address(this) generates exception, how to obtain the correct value for address(this)

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, assert

I have modified the following code from a michalzalecki website https://michalzalecki.com/ethereum-test-driven-introduction-to-solidity/ to test address(this):

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/Funding.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";

contract FundingTest {
  address v = 0xBFF7fd8064C448347e239FD7B7347b6D959Fb9f2;
  function testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract() public {
    Funding funding = Funding(DeployedAddresses.Funding());
    //Assert.equal(funding.owner(), address(this), "An owner is different than a deployer");
    //Assert.equal(funding.owner(), msg.sender , "An owner is different than a deployer");
    Assert.equal(v, address(this), "An owner is different than a deployer");

  }
}
```

My contract code is:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract Funding {
  address public owner;
  constructor() public {
     owner = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

When I run the truffle migrate, I got following addresses:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x59d01a9d031010d4b0cc7d0d7db87d8d7c5d2a96f9ec1117512c1ec73e578321
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x258B8538F1dA81DC872A21f38782B548BA849efc
   > block number:        1
   > block timestamp:     1631809265
   > account:             0x05A4de8a003419dF5e51fF20D36750e990a32C1e


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying 'Funding'
   -------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xbbe3ba94cc623931990c1b802ced466b7854378a89c02c5d3adf0742b8a571aa
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xBFF7fd8064C448347e239FD7B7347b6D959Fb9f2
   > block number:        3
   > block timestamp:     1631809266
   > account:             0x05A4de8a003419dF5e51fF20D36750e990a32C1e
   > balance:             99.99291392
```

I am getting the following exception message when I run the truffle test:

```
$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.
   
    /home/zulfi/Truffle_programs/michal-unboxRem/test/FundingTest.sol:9:5: Warning: Unused local variable.
    Funding funding = Funding(DeployedAddresses.Funding());
    ^-------------^

> Artifacts written to /tmp/test--7766-a2isLlv7uM20
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang



  FundingTest
    1) testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (6s)
  1 failing

  1) FundingTest
       testSettingAnOwnerOfDeployedContract:
     Error: An owner is different than a deployer
      at checkResultForFailure (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:66:1)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Somebody please guide how to avoid the exception, how to retrieve the correct value of address(this), why migration value does not work?

Zulfi.

Comment: You have to clarify your intent. What are you trying to achieve? [address(this)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40018/what-is-addressthis-in-solidity) returns the address of the contract itself.

Comment: Do you want to test the contract was deployed by `0xBFF7fd8064C448347e239FD7B7347b6D959Fb9f2`? In that case the test should be `Assert.equal(v, funding.owner(), "An owner is different than a deployer");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`address(this)` will return the address of the `FundingTest` contract, so of course it will be different from the `Funding` contract. The test should pass if you use `address(funding)`, assuming your address for `v` is correct.