# Retrieving the token number of a transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

`A` address sends `X` amount of token to `B` address. As this transaction happens inside the interface `function _transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)` I know that the `amount` variable holds the token number that `A` sends to `B`.

My question is: does the `address` type has a function which let me retrieve `amount` after transfer has been called by referring to the transaction address? Not historically, just until the current contract's (contract of one transaction) lifecycle ends.

Based on this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29469/is-addressthis-a-valid-address-in-a-contracts-constructor) I assume `address(this)` returns the contract's own address and can be called with `balanceOf` but it won't return a value until I don't call `_transfer`. Is it right?

```
 function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
      uint256 tokenAmountInCurrentContract = amount;
      //...
 }

 function retrieveCurrentContractTokenAmount() internal returns (bool) {
      // would this do it?          
      return balanceOf(address(this));
 }
 
 function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
      return _balances[account];
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The function balanceOf should be usable at any time. If you call it before _mint it should return the previous balance, and after _mint it should return the new balance.

Comment: @Ismael I am implementing a tax feature and I see everybody is sending the swapped ETH to address(this)