# How to set variable of contract from another contract constructor? Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, cpp-ethereum, constructor

I have a contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^ 0.8.15;

contract MomContract {
    bool public failed =false;
    constructor(){
        new Son(address(this));

    }
    function SetFailed(bool _failed) public{
        failed=_failed;
    }


}
contract Son{
    constructor(address _mom){
        MomContract mom=MomContract(_mom);
        mom.SetFailed(true);
       
    }
    
}
```

When I try to deploy it with remix, it fails with revert

```
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I see no error in it, but how do I communicate from contract to contract?

Comment: You can access the address but you cannot call it. Contracts that are being constructed cannot be called. Refer to to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31102/24693) in the Q&A link I shared above.

Comment: Oh, yeah that really helps, thanks!

Comment: No worries. A side note: in Solidity the community standard is to use [`camelCase`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/style-guide.html#function-names) for naming functions.